# Print out the value uint8_t *

Tags: c

The followings are my snippet:

```
typedef struct{
   uint8_t dstEndpt;
   uint16_t srcEndpt;
   uint8_t * quality;
} DataIndT;

DataIndT * dataIndPtr;

printf("dstEndpt: 0x%02x", dataIndPtr->dstEndpt); <-- print out the value of dstEndpt

printf("dstEndpt: 0x%04x", dataIndPtr->srcEndpt); <-- print out the value of srcEndpt
```

However, how can I print out the value of `quality` ?

Comment: `quality` is a pointer like an array, if you want to print the value that points to you need to specify it. with the index or dereferencing it.

Comment: @wallek876, would you mind showing an example ?

Comment: @user3815726  `quality[0]` or `*quality` he meant.

Comment: This post twice asks about printing a _pointer_, yet OP accepts an answer that answers how to print what is pointed to.  Suggest appending a clarification to the post or consider a matching answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`quality` is a pointer, or like an array, if you want to print the value that points to you need to specify it. with the index or dereferencing it:

```
printf("quality: %d", *(dataIndPtr->quality));
```

Using the zero index like if it was an array should also print the value:

```
printf("quality: %d", dataIndPtr->quality[0]);
```

Or if what you want is print the value of the pointer itself then Michal's answer is what you want.

Comment: @this yeah, you're right i didn't notice just copied from the question, i'll update it.

Comment: @this it is *a* correct specifier. Without repeating our last debate, `%x` can be used for non-negative values of any type narrower than `int` because they undergo the default argument promotions. In practical terms it is a good choice because some libraries don't support the modifiers added in C99

Comment: @MattMcNabb No. %x is for only unsigned int: `o,u,x,X The unsigned int argument...` Did you read the Standard yet?

Comment: @this "The correct one is*: `printf("%d",x);` This is because of default argument promotions as printf() is variadic function. This means that unsigned char value is always promoted to int." http://stackoverflow.com/a/27547422/995714 did you really understand the standard? `uint8_t` will be promoted to `int`, not `unsigned int`

Comment: @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc "unsigned char value is always promoted to int." is not always true.  On rare platforms, `UCHAR_MAX > INT_MAX`.  In those platforms, expect `unsigned char` to be promoted to `unsigned`.  (Note the * in your comment's referenced answer.)

Comment: @chux yes I know, I just quote the original answer. In this case `uint8_t` exists, so `CHAR_BIT` must be 8 and `sizeof(char) < sizeof(int)`, therefore `uint8_t` will always be promoted to int

Comment: @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc True about `uint8_t` and `CHAR_BIT must be 8`.

Answer (score 8):

> However, how can I print out the value of quality ?

You do

```
printf("%p", (void*) dataIndPtr->quality);
```

This will print address, since value of pointer is address to object to which pointer points.

---

To print the *object* where the pointer points, in this case, you can use format specifiers available for C99 (also need to include `inttypes.h`). Of course you also need to dereference the pointer:

```
printf("%" PRIu8 "\n", *(dataIndPtr->quality));
```

since `quality` is pointer to `uint8_t` or

```
printf("%" PRIu16 "\n", *(dataIndPtr->srcEndpt));
```

for `uint16_t` types.

Answer (score 3):

To print the value of a pointer, use `%p`:

```
printf("dstEndpt: %p", (void*)dataIndPtr->quality);
```

Comment: see this question -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633067/p-format-specifier-in-c.

Comment: @ameyCU the value of a pointer is the address of the object it is pointing to.  Printing the address of the pointer would involve `&dataIndPtr->quality`, which OP is not interested in

Answer (score 1):

Like @Giorgi pointed you can use **inttypes.h**.

Here is a small example:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void){

    uint8_t a = 0;
    uint16_t b = 0;
    uint32_t c = 0;
    uint64_t d = 0;


    printf("%" PRId8 "\n", a);
    printf("%" PRIu16 "\n",b);
    printf("%" PRIu32 "\n", c);
    printf("%" PRIu64 "\n", d);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: for uint_8 also do we need to use(in printf) "PRId8 " or "PRuId8 " is there?