# How to solve this error when trying to compute the twoSums coding question in C

Tags: c, arrays, memory, dynamic

Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.

Given nums = [2, 7, 11, 15], target = 9,

Because nums[0] + nums[1] = 2 + 7 = 9,
return [0, 1].

```
#include<stdio.h>
int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target);

int main(){

    int*array;
    int arraySize;
    scanf("%d",&arraySize);
    for (int i=0;i<arraySize;i++){
        scanf("%d",&array[i]);
    }

    int target;
    scanf("%d",&target);
    int* positions=twoSum(array, arraySize, target);
    printf("The positions are: %p",positions);
    return 0;
}


int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target){
    int *returnSize = NULL;
    for(int i=0,sum=0;i<numsSize;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<numsSize;j++){
            sum =sum+nums[i]+nums[j];
            if(sum==target){
                returnSize[0]=nums[i];
                returnSize[1]=nums[j];
            }
            else 
                returnSize[0]= -1;
                returnSize[1]= -1;
        }
    }
    return returnSize;
}
```

The error I am getting makes reference to a line that is empty in my code. Please help

Comment: Please allocate some memory for `int*array;` which `scanf` does not do for you. Also `int *returnSize = NULL;` has no memory allocation, so it can't be dereferenced.

Comment: Note too that `printf("The positions are: %p",positions);` will not print the array contents. There are a lot of mistakes in this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some mistakes in your code:

### memory allocation

You declare pointers on `int` to store data to process and result, but you do not allocate memory: `malloc` is for Memory ALLOCation:

```
array = malloc(sizeof *array * arraySize);
```

and

```
int *returnSize = malloc(sizeof *returnSize * 2);
```

### Sum calculation logic

#### `sum` value

In `twoSum` function, the `sum` variable is getting bigger and bigger: `sum =sum+nums[i]+nums[j];`

Instead, a simple `if (target == nums[i] + nums[j])` will perform the test you wanted.

#### `sum` test

In your code, each time `sum` is not equal to `target`, you reset `returnSize[0]` to `-1`

You do not have to have an `else` clause: you can initialize the `returnSize` before the `for` loop.

#### missing `{...}`

Look at your first code: for any value of sum and target, `returnSize[1]` is set to `-1` because you've forgotten to put accolades after the `else` (but, as written before, you do not even need an `else`)

`gcc` can warn you about such issue (`-Wmisleading-indentation`, or better `-Wall`)

```
    for(int j=0;j<numsSize;j++){
        sum =sum+nums[i]+nums[j];
        if(sum==target){
            returnSize[0]=nums[i];
            returnSize[1]=nums[j];
        }
        else 
            returnSize[0]= -1;
        returnSize[1]= -1;
    }
```

---

Considering this, you can write a code that do what you wanted.

Be careful, you should test the `scanf` and `malloc` return values too...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int *twoSum(int *nums, int numsSize, int target);

int main()
{
    int *array;
    int arraySize;

    // TODO: test that scanf returned 1
    scanf("%d", &arraySize);

    // TODO: test that arraysize is at least 2

    /* allocate array to store the numbers*/
    array = malloc(sizeof *array * arraySize);

    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        // TODO: test that scanf returned 1
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }

    int target;
    // TODO: test that scanf returned 1
    scanf("%d", &target);
    int *positions = twoSum(array, arraySize, target);
    printf("The positions are: %d(%d) %d(%d)\n", positions[0], array[positions[0]], positions[1], array[positions[1]]);


    /* memory has been allocated? free it */
    free(positions)
    free(array)

    return 0;
}

int *twoSum(int *nums, int numsSize, int target)
{
    int *returnSize = malloc(sizeof *returnSize * 2);

    returnSize[0] = returnSize[1] = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < numsSize; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numsSize; j++) {
            if (target ==nums[i] + nums[j] ) {
                returnSize[0] = i;
                returnSize[1] = j;
                return returnSize;
            }
        }
    }
    return returnSize;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

there are mistakes in this code.First you should allocate memory for `int*array;` after taking `int arraySize;` as input , you can do it like this

`array = malloc(sizeof(int) * arraySize);`

then here `%p` is not appropriate , instead use `%d`. Take look here for more information about `%p` [%p format specifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633067/p-format-specifier-in-c) and also since you want to print 2 positions you need to call two arguments in `printf` like this `printf("The positions are: %d %d", positions[0], positions[1]);`

In your `twoSum` function , you need to allocate memory for  `int* returnSize ;` like this `returnSize = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);`

and here you are not returning positions of found elements , you are returning elements themselfs.

```
            if(sum==target){
                returnSize[0]=nums[i];
                returnSize[1]=nums[j];
            }
```

also you need to add `return` in this `if-statement` other wise , you will traverse array completely and `returnSize` elements will become `-1` again(unless answer is too last element of array)

so this `if` should be like this:

```
            if (sum == target) {
                returnSize[0] = i;//num[i] is not position. it is element of array
                returnSize[1] = j;//num[j] is not position .it is element of array
                return returnSize;//otherwise it will traverse array compeltely and they -1 again
            }
```

also only if you code one line for `if,else,while,for,...` (conditional statements) ,you can avoid using braces ,otherwise only one line of your code will executed ,if that condition become true ,so you have to add a block for this `else`:

```
            else
            {
                returnSize[0] = -1;
                returnSize[1] = -1;
            }//coding more than one line so your else should be in a block
```

and also here  `sum=sum+num[i]+num[j];` is wrong you should change this to `sum=num[i]+num[j];` because you only want to check sum of two current number ,or better way don't use sum at all only check equality of target with `num[i]+num[j]`

here is complete code:

```
int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target);

int main() {

    int* array;
    int arraySize;
    scanf("%d", &arraySize);
    array = malloc(sizeof(int) * arraySize);//allocate memory for array
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }

    int target;
    scanf("%d", &target);
    int* positions = twoSum(array, arraySize, target);
    printf("The positions are: %d %d", positions[0], positions[1]);//%p is for not for content of array
    return 0;
}


int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target) {
    int* returnSize ;
    returnSize = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < numsSize; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numsSize; j++) {             
            if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target) {
                returnSize[0] = i;//num[i] is not position. it is element of array
                returnSize[1] = j;//num[j] is not position .it is element of array
                return returnSize;//otherwise it will traverse array compeltely and they -1 again
            }
            else
            {
                returnSize[0] = -1;
                returnSize[1] = -1;
            }//coding more than one line so your else should be in a block
        }
    }
    return returnSize;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here your code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdbool.h>

int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target);
void print_pos(int * arr, int i) {
    printf("test %d\n", i);
    if (arr != NULL) {
        printf("position 1 = %d, position 2 = %d\n", arr[0], arr[1]);
    } else
        printf("Not found\n");
}

int main(){

    int array[5] = {5, 6, 2 ,1 ,3} ;

    int target1 = 11, target2 = 9, target3 = 15;
    int * positions1=twoSum(array, 5, target1);
    int * positions2=twoSum(array, 5, target2);
    int * positions3=twoSum(array, 5, target3);

    print_pos(positions1, 1);
    print_pos(positions2, 2);
    print_pos(positions3, 3);

    return 0;
}


int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target){
    int *return_arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
    bool found = false;
    for(int i=0;i<numsSize;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<numsSize;j++){
            if((nums[i]+nums[j])==target){
                return_arr[0]= i;
                return_arr[1]= j;
                found = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (found)
        return return_arr;
    else {
        free(return_arr);
        return NULL;
    }
}
```